# Drop-down menu - items dependence

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8pnm/) is the entire code for my menu. I'm not posting it here again for clarity.

Some code explanation:

`id="onlink"` means the link is clicked. The page is active.

What I want is when `MENU` is `onlink`, its entire submenu (here both: `submenu` and `submenu2`) should become visible too (note we have not clicked any particular submenu).

Is it possible to establish such dependency in pure css?

So far the submenu only pops up on menu hover and disappears after it.

Comment: P.S - Notice that in the future if you'll have multiple dropdown menus, you're going to have to define `z-index`es etc. to the `.sub-menu`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand your selector to include every `.sub-menu` which is after `#onlink` using the [`General sibling selector (~)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

```
#menu li:hover .sub-menu,
#menu #onlink ~ .sub-menu {
    display:block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Y8pnm/3/)

Comment: yet even better solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking to get the submenus to be hovered as well even after the `MENU` is not `ONLINK`. Here is a solution. Hope this is what you are looking for. I used the `opacity` css property.

```
#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
}

    #menu li ul.sub-menu a {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        display: block;
    }

    #menu li:hover .sub-menu {
       opacity:1;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y8pnm/2/

Comment: You have thought ahead of me actually. This is a feature I will try to implement soon so thank you very much for solution. I accept Itay's answer though for solving my initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could make MENU and it's submenu share the same class and then use

```
.class:hover {
  // Your CSS code
}
```